# PHP create multiple directories

Tags: php

Let's say, in PHP, I am trying to put an image in a specific directory that is on root.

I want to put it on `/images/afc/esp/stadium/` directory. Images folder, Federation folder, Country ISO3 folder, content folder.

```
$folder_full = "images/".$getFed."/".$country_folder."/stadiums";
if (!is_dir($folder_full)) mkdir($folder_full);
```

Before you ask, yes `$getFed` and `$country_folder` work and output text. So, then I get this error: `Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory`

I don't get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of your subdirectories don't exist so you either need to iteratively create them or set the 3rd argument to `mkdir()` to `true`. Note that the second argument are the directory permissions (ignored on Windows) which default to `0777`.

You also need to set `$folder_full` to the root using `/`.

```
$folder_full = "/images/{$getFed}/{$country_folder}/stadiums";
if (!is_dir($folder_full)) mkdir($folder_full, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the recursive parameter to add directories that don't exist in the path you provide: `mkdir($folder_full, 0777, true)`

See the PHP docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 3):

All the intermediary directories have to already exist. You can trigger this behaviour by using the optional third argument:

```
mkdir($folder_full,0777,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in normal cPanel the folder permissions should be 0755
so the command in this case will be:

```
mkdir('tst/tst2/tst3', 0755, true);
```